# Trigger onChange when new props are received

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that wraps `<input>` so that I can add functionality to provide an updating default value. Here's example usage:

```
<Input type="text" follow={this.state.someData} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
```

So when the state of the parent updates, this child component receives new props, which it uses to (possibly) update the value of the wrapped `input` element (code snippets, not the whole thing):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({value: nextProps.follow})
}

render() {
  input_props = this.props
  input_props.onChange = this.props.onChange //being explicit for clarity
  input_props.value = this.state.value
  return React.createElement(
    'input',
    input_props
  )
}
```

However, this update does NOT trigger the `onChange` handler. Theoretically, if I can create an appropriate `SyntheticEvent`, then I can just `this.props.onChange(event)`, but I can't find information on creating that object.

I'm open to other solutions as well, if you have them.

Edit:

Interesting. The event is getting called (woops!) but the `event.target` is the original element, not the `Input` element:

```
<input type="text" id='1' onChange={(e) => {this.setState({someData: e.target.value})} />
<Input type="text" id='2' follow={this.state.someData} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
```

`onChangeHandler` receives an event from the first input (id=1), rather than the second. This was causing my event handler to error, since it was expecting information that wasn't present.

Edit 2: Pretty sure I still want to handle this the same way - I still want the wrapped `input` to throw an `onChange` event as if it had been changed.

Comment: You need to pass the onChangehandler from props to the input elements props

Comment: Yeah, I realized that didn't happen in the code snippet. It's occurring in the actual code, so I update the snippet code to include it (very explicitly).

Comment: Edit: Actually, it might be that my event is crashing, and I just hadn't noticed :3 BRB